# Add a sticky class to node displayed via View

Tags: views, 8, theming

How to add class for sticky nodes in Drupal 8, so I can theme views (sticky having different background etc).

I have seen a post that it can be done through Twig, but I cannot understand in which template should I put the lines and frankly...which lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get the sticky class on views-row in most themes if your Format Show is set to `Content`.

But if it's set to `Fields` you can do it through the interface with the help of **Content: Sticky at top of lists** field.

1. Add the `Sticky at top of lists` field from `Content` Category to your View
2. Under `Output format` setting for this field choose **Custom** and then enter your desired class name into the offered field:
   **Custom output for TRUE**
   `node--sticky`
   **Custom output for FALSE**
   [____leave empty____]
3. Under `Rewrite results` uncollapse the **Replacement patterns** and copy the code for this field. It will be something like `{{ sticky }}`.

   Don't enable Rewriting, this step is just to copy the pattern.
4. Save the Field settings and check the views results - do you see the class name listed for nodes that you know are stickied? If yes then edit the field again and **Exclude from display**
5. Under **Format: Settings** paste the pattern into the **Row class** input field

You will now have the text you entered for the TRUE sticky state appear as one of the classes next to `views-row` class.